How do I prevent overflows in my C# SoftMax implementation?
In my efforts to understand machine learning better from a "first principles" perspective, I am implementing my own ML-related functions.  Currently I am trying to implement SoftMax:
IEnumerable<double> SoftMax(IEnumerable<double> vector)
{
    var exps = vector.Select(v => Math.Exp(v));
    var sumExps = exps.Sum();
    return exps.Select(exp => exp / sumExps);
}

If I understand SoftMax correctly, if I sum the results of this function, i.e., SoftMax(vector).Sum(), the output should always be 1.
In nearly all cases, however, this returns a value that's either slightly greater than or slightly less than 1.  Generally, something like 1.0568102998178908 or 0.9758570985704772.
I've heard that this is not uncommon (it's basically an overflow issue), and can be fixed by subtracting the largest element of the input from the value that's being fed into Math.Exp().  So I came up with this implementation based on suggestions:
IEnumerable<double> SoftMax(IEnumerable<double> vector)
{
    var maxVal = vector.Max();
    var exps = vector.Select(v => Math.Exp(v - maxVal));
    var sumExps = exps.Sum();
    return exps.Select(exp => exp / sumExps);
}

In testing my implementation, I am passing in a random collection of doubles, as follows:
IEnumerable<double> vector = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(n => new Random().NextDouble());
var softMaxVec = SoftMax(vector);
Console.WriteLine(softMaxVec.Sum());

But my improved implementation still gives me the same problem.  What am I doing wrong?  Or am I misunderstanding something about how SoftMax is supposed to work?

It appears to have nothing to do with overflows. You seem to be falling victim to floating point maths. In the same way that 1/3 isn't a nice number in base 10, just can't precisely store some values in binary. FYI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Also, even without issues due to some fractions not storing well in binary, you're working within 64 bits of data for each number, so you won't have all the decimal places. If we divide a load of numbers by their sum, and then truncate the results to 3 decimal places (example) and then sum them, we're not going to get 1. We'll get close, but not 1. If we round each result to 3dp, we might get over 1.

Thanks @ProgrammingLlama this is very helpful.  For the sake of ML, do the floating point inaccuracies matter?  Would my SoftMax function work well in a demanding production ML environment?  Or is there a better way to do this in C#?

I don't really have any direct experience with ML but I would think that it's likely close enough, considering ML itself is imprecise and we're probably only talking about small variations from the true  values.

It shouldn't be a problem from an ML perspective if your softmax probabilities don't precisely add up to 1. But with your examples they are off by 3-5% which I think can be a problem.

The fact they are so far out should ring alarms that this is not double imprecision - you'd expect something around the 12-14th decimal place, maybe more with compounding, but it would be hard to go out by so much by any stretch of the imagination.

The problem is in your test code.
IEnumerable<double> vector = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(n => new Random().NextDouble());
var softMaxVec = SoftMax(vector);
Console.WriteLine(softMaxVec.Sum());

Due to deferred execution, if you iterate through the same vector multiple times, you get different numbers. For example
Random random = new Random();
IEnumerable<double> randomNumbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(_ => random.NextDouble());
foreach (var number in randomNumbers)
{
     Console.WriteLine(number);
}
Console.WriteLine('\n')
foreach (var number in randomNumbers)
{
     Console.WriteLine(number);
}

produces
0.63632565114476
0.440262559540692
0.254312404549826

0.566282945483123
0.348965338128137
0.983789030920616

And in your softmax implementation you iterate through the vector multiple times and each time it is effectively using different random number vectors (one vector for exponentiation, one vector for summation).
Just test it with a hardcoded test case like
SoftMax(new List<double> { 0.443426089567796, 0.234234, 0.343454, 0.3 });

And it shows that your softmax works fine. In general to achieve test stability it's not a good idea to write test cases that use random inputs anyway.

Excellent answer. Any IDE will warn of "multiple enumeration of IEnumerable" but so many devs ignore it. This is a good demonstration why not to: deferred execution. The function in the OP's code should either take a concrete collection like array or list or similar, and if not, copy it into one before iterating over it. Similarly, returning IEnumerable<T> is the right thing to do only in a very few, rare cases.
